# Data Sync Between Desktop-Mobile via USB in Cordova/Ionic Application

Tags: mysql, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid mobile application using Cordova/Ionic/Angular Js. My requirement is to Sync the Data (or in other words prefill the mobile DB ) from the Desktop(where the Mysql DB is residing) with the SQLite Db (residing in the phone) when i connect the phone to the desktop through USB. I can't use Web Services since the app has to run in an offline mode.

I have done a lot of searching for that but all i could is the solution for Android app(native) where they are mentioning to use JDBC /Socket Programming. I have found one cordova content sync plugin but i think it again requires the internet connectivity , is there any cordova plugin that can help in that? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Who should perform the sync? The mobile device or the desktop computer?

I would suggest the following:

- Enable USB Debugging in Android
- Desktop computer should have adb drivers installed.
- Use adb commands to communicate with your device (i.e. pull the database, perform some updates, push the database)

There is a tool on github which does something similar, maybe you can look at the source to get and idea how to do this: https://github.com/google/adb-sync

Comment: Thanks for the help Jurgen.I think the mobile app will initiate the sync. so if i use this adb sync i will get the Database file in the mobile.But how will i read i mean how will i insert the data into SQLite Db programmatically. I appreciate your help as i am a beginner in this concept so getting difficulty in forming an end to end process.

Comment: Well modern smartphones are designed as `always connected devices` the do not ship with sync frameworks like old `windows mobile` or `palm` devices. I don't think you can easily achive this. Your best bet would be to enable `USB tethering` on your smartphone and connect to the ip adress of the host pc (it should get a unique ip adress on a newly created network device).

Comment: Hi Jurgen..I found a way to do that..Just let me know if i am thinking in a right direction. I am planning to get the mysql dump using Cordova Bluetooth plugin , once i have it in my Tab i can read the file using Cordova local file reader plugin and insert the data into Database programmaticaly. Will it be feasible?